# notification deleteIntent doesn't work when app close

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

a create push notification with next code:

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                .setTicker(getRewardStr)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentIntent(clickPendingIntent)
                .setDeleteIntent(cancelPendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(description)
                .addAction(rewardAction)
                .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIconBitmap);
```

**in general - everything works ok**, i receive all events via broadcast

but I just mention that if notification shows when app is open and than i swipe app from recent, than my notification is canceled but i didn't receive `cancelPendingIntent`.
is this some kind of default behaviour?
is there any way to catch notification cancel in this situation?

Comment: what do you mean by swipe app from recent?

Comment: add your error logcat

Comment: @ErginErsoy i mean that i close app by swiping app from recent apps.

Comment: @kamalverma there is no error.

Comment: i try your situation with google play notifications, but the notification didn't disappear. So there should be a problem.

Comment: @ErginErsoy any ideas?

Comment: not yet but i will search for you.

Comment: For gmail if i open application notification dissappear. Is there any change you are triggering that cause notification is opened